# Submit input field with button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

Here I have an input field and button:

```
<input id="pac-input" class="controls" type="text" placeholder="Search! e.g. Pizza, Pharmacy, Post office">

<button id="new" class="btn btn-success">Submit</button>
```

Now when I type something into input fields and press "enter" I submit input fields

How to make this append when I click on button? So when I click on button to submit input fields?

**UPDATE: I just want when I click on btton to simulate submit on input field**

Comment: Why the downvotes guys?  Kinda a newbie question but we were all there once.  Obviously English isn't this guy's first language, no need to penalize him for growing up somewhere else in the world- either correct it by editing the question or move on...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Using jQuery**

`$("#formID").submit()`

http://api.jquery.com/submit/

**Using HTML**

```
<form>
    <input ... />
    <button type="submit" ...>Submit</button>
</form>
```

http://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML/Elements/button

Answer (score 0):

The  element can be written just like that. But if you do, you will have different results in different browsers. Most browsers make a button that says “Submit,” but Firefox makes a button that says “Submit Query.” To change what the button says, you should add a value attribute:

**FOR INPUT ELEMENT**:

add or change the query like this.

**FOR BUTTON:**

The BUTTON element requires both an opening tag  and a closing tag  When you use it, any content you enclose inside the tag will be enclosed in a button. Then you activate the button with a script.

Submit Form
You can include images in your button or combine images and text to create a more interesting button.

Submit Form

**FOR COMMAND:**

If you want your command to be represented by an image, you use the icon attribute.